# How to start the default music player from my app?

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I make a app with a `ListView`. When I tap on a `ListView` item, a `.ogg` soundfile should start playing. Not in my app, but in the default music player app of the user. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/song.mp3");
it.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/mp3");
startActivity(it);
```

Or

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "1");   
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);   
startActivity(it);
```

Extracted from http://snipt.net/Martin/android-intent-usage/

I haven't tested myself.

Comment: this plays only the song in the internal memory or a specific song from sd card. How to do it if i to load all songs from SD card to mediaplayr.

Answer (score 1):

dunno if this directly applies to the question, but here is a way to open the Play Music app from your own app:

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.music");
if (i == null)
     throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File(uri);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
    ActivityChatView.mContext.startActivity(intent);
```